# Links not opening in target frame

Tags: target, frames

I'm trying to open links from the left frame (accounts) in the right frame (main) but it only opens in a new tab.  What am I missing?

Frames:

```
  echo '
   <frameset cols = "20%,80%">
      <frame name="accounts" src="accounts.php"/>
      <frame name="main" src="http://torax.outwar.com/world.php" />
   </frameset>
   ';
```

Accounts Page:

```
$accounts = array(191022,699195);
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    echo "<a href='http://torax.outwar.com/world.php?suid=" . $account ."' target='main'>".$account."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: frames were deprecated two decades ago. Id be shocked if they worked on all of chrome/firefox/edge desktop/mobile. Consider adopting iframes instead. Try something like <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> as your intro tags but this may prevent HTML5 features from working.

Comment: I tried switching to an iframe and it still opens in a new tab.

<iframe name='main' width=1600 height=850 src='http://torax.outwar.com/world.php'></iframe>''

Comment: with iframes, you set the content by the iframes src attribute, like href='javascript:document.getElementsByName("main")[0].src='http://torax.outwar.com/world...